# How to reuse the processed data for parallel jobs with Spark Fair scheduler

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark fair scheduler to trigger parallel spark jobs. The dataFrame below is common data result processed before this save action.

```
dataFrame.rdd.map(save(_))
```

From DAG, I found each job has the repeated stages to process the dataframe.  I have PB level data processing so it will be efficient to reuse the dataFrame processed result.

1. How should I make the dataFrame processing to be shared and reused
   by each job ?
2. Is possible to create partition to have different running for the
   same partition or .... ?
3. Or what is the best practice to approach this other than triggering
   paralleling jobs ?